# Ошибка при обращении SslStream

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

Вот Ошибка:
Эта операция допустима только при использовании контекста, подлинность которого успешно подтверждена.
Вот Код Сервера:

```
using System.Net.Security;
internal static SslStream sslStream;

tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
tcpListener.Start();
TcpClient сlient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
Stream = client.GetStream();
sslStream = new SslStream(Stream);

string message = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);

sslStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Код Клиента:

```
using System.Net.Security;
internal static SslStream sslStream;

client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
stream = client.GetStream();
sslStream = new SslStream(stream);

sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("127.0.0.1");

string message = userName;

byte[] data = new byte[1024];

sslStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя просто начать читать/писать с `SslStream`, предварительно нужно вызвать один из методов: `AuthenticateAsClient`/`AuthenticateAsServer`. На стороне сервера вы не вызываете ничего, поэтому получаете ошибку.

Что бы всё работало, вам нужно создать/получить сертификат.

Минимальный рабочий пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serverThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
        server.Start();
        var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        var ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"rsa-4096.pfx", "hh87$-Jqo");
        ssl.AuthenticateAsServer(cert);
        ssl.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world"), 0, 11);
        ssl.Flush();
        ssl.Close();
        server.Stop();
    });

    var clientThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345);
        // последний параметр отключает проверку серверного сертификата
        var ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, (a, b, c, d) => true);
        ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ssl, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            string recivedText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(recivedText);
        }
    });

    serverThread.Start();
    clientThread.Start();

    serverThread.Join();
    clientThread.Join();
}
```

Сертификат для примера: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/ConsoleTest/rsa-4096.pfx

Comment: Возможно, распишете чуть более подробно? Имху, на текущий момент как-то слишком кратко и непонятно.

Comment: Я знаю что нужно вызвать этот метод, но я не знаю что нужно передать в аргументах. Я смотрел и в документации, и на MDSN и stackoverflow но я не понял откуда взять ssl сертификат;

Comment: @Gweston я обновил ответ, можете поискать, как создавать сертификаты и что это такое. Если что-то не будет получаться, задайте новый вопрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl пример как создать сертификат для вашего случая при помощи openssl

Comment: Я понял как создать, но как подключить, я понял что нужно в файле проекта создать сертификат,  и с помощью System.IO.File.ReadAllText(путь к файлу) в переменной передать в AuthenticateAsServer

Comment: @Gweston посмотрите класс X509Certificate2, там есть или конструктор, или статический метод, который читает сертификат из файла (или из массива байт)

Comment: X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("полный путь к файлу .pem", "пароль"); sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate); Видает: "Требуемый объект не найден."

Comment: @Gweston не знаю что это, в меня все работает. Вот мой сертификат https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/ConsoleTest/rsa-4096.pfx и пароль от него `hh87$-Jqo`

Comment: @Gweston добавил пример кода

Comment: Работает !!!!!!                                                                                                     p.s. знаешь в чем была проблема : я забил поставить "@" перед путем, и я потратил пол часа чтобы разобраться :)

Comment: и не подскажешь можно ли добавить криптографическое шифрование сообщений, или ето не ненужно  так как ssl ето уже зашифрованное соединение.

Comment: @Gweston это лишнее, ssl создан для того, что бы никто не мог изменять, читать, и подставлять мусор вместо передаваемых данных